# Why didn't they call for this character's help sooner?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-infinity-war

We see in the post credit scene of *Avengers: Infinity War*, where Nick Fury seemingly sends a message for help to Captain Marvel and he has her number on speed dial, or if that was a pager.

In an interview, Kevin Feige stated that Captain Marvel would be the strongest character they have introduced.

So why did Nick Fury didn't call for her help sooner? She could've helped them defeat early on when he hadn't gathered all of the Infinity Stones.

Answer (score 29):

When I saw the movie I thought the same thing, like where is Nick Fury in all this chaos. My only way to explain the situation is that **Nick Fury probably doesn't even know that anything is happening in Wakanda at all.**

In the post credit scene, we see him, on what looks like any other day, there is no panic on the streets, he is not rushing anywhere to do something like you would in a middle of a world ending event.

Also when Thanos's henchmen came to New York, they shortly fought Iron Man and the others, and soon, carried them into space, where they would stay for the rest of the movie. That way Iron Man couldn't really inform him of anything.

All of the events that occur afterwards in the movie are happening very fast, one after another so there isn't really any time gap, or time jump, between start and finish of the movie.

One could say, how can't he know, the New York attack was all over the news?
That is true, but only consequence of that event is Tony Stark missing, they didn't attack New York with an army like they did in Wakanda, so that really wasn't a world ending event so that he needs to call Captain Marvel (they've seen much worse). And like I said, while they may be investigating what happened to Tony, other events are all happening very fast that they simply didn't have the time to hear what is happening at Wakanda (probably on the same day).

Comment: Man, the attack on New York was pretty severe, and wouldn't the presence of a big ass spaceship be all over the news? And the moment we see everything alright and subsequent eruption of chaos at the road, was after Thanos snapped his fingers. What was he doing until then?

Comment: I would very much like to believe that. But with the scene shown Agent Hill and Fury were together. That shows that there was some organization they were working for ( Shield's successor?). This is further supported by the fact that Fury calls the situation a code red. I can't believe he wouldn't have heard about the attack, with the position and power that Nick Fury has over intelligence resources.

Comment: Is a spaceship, or chaos of any sort, over NYC out of the ordinary at this point in the MCU?  Seems to me like these sort of things are a regular occurrence.

Comment: I agree with this one -- I think Fury knew what was going on in NYC, but no one other than the Avengers understood the stakes. I know it's not "canon" MCU, but consider Agents of Shield this past week as well, where the "sad events" in NYC are mentioned in passing, but they don't lose focus on the Gravitonium problem (even the aliens attacking the Lighthouse seem blissfully unaware). (Again, not truly MCU, I'm reasonably sure no one is going to fizzle out of existence on AoS next week. But worth mentioning.)

Comment: Didn't Bruce Banner stay behind? And we know that at the very least, there was enough time for the GotG to find Thor, go to Knowhere, and then go to Titan.

Comment: Nick Fury not know about something as major as Thanos collecting the Infinity Stones and all that? Not bloody likely...

Answer (score 15):

> So why did Nick Fury didn't call for her help sooner?

The situation was **contained** within the AVENGERS throughout the movie until the big blowout which resulted in the world knowing what happened. Let us consider the movie events:

1. A big circular spaceship arrives... A fight occurs in New York and promptly by the end of the fight, the spaceship is out of New York and Earth. So in this perspective, the Avengers have already succeeded and there are no more spaceships...
2. Bruce Banner ***contacts*** Cap and until Cap and co. meets Rhodey in Avengers facility, the council was merely thinking of the accords and all...
3. The next big event occurs in Wakanda and considering it's top-secret status, it's not known much outside...

### TLDR: The Thanos threat was not known until much later...

Now let us consider the perspective of Nick Fury:

1. He believed in the Avengers for the first alien invasion when apparently he could have Captain Marvel then and there...
2. Ultron was handled by the Avengers when Captain Marvel could have knocked them out..

So Captain Marvel was reserved only for ***extinction-level events*** dubbed ***CODE RED*** and considering people were *dis-integrating* in front of him, he assumes the Avengers have failed and that's when he goes for the last option available... As to why she is considered for only and extinction-level event, we have to wait for the "Captain Marvel" movie.

Comment: It's also quite possible that Fury hasn't established contact or a relationship with Captain Marvel until just recently. I'm sure the Captain Marvel standalone movie will explain how everything fits together.

Comment: Recent set photos from the Captain Marvel movie show a younger Nick Fury (with both eyes) with Captain Marvel, and so it seems that a relationship exists, though what kind is undefined at the moment...

Comment: I read also that Captain Marvel is the first that Fury meets, the hero that he's had the longest relationship with, or to that effect.

Comment: The movie is said to occur in the 90s and might hold the answer to how Fury loses his one good eye and it also has Ronan the Accuser and young Coulson so there's that!

Comment: It's also possible that before Fury uses the pager, Captain Marvel is somehow immune to the extinction event (e.g. not technically alive or not technically inside the universe). If she had been called earlier, and failed, there would be a good chance she'd be dead by the end of the movie.

Answer (score 4):

SHIELD was basically destroyed after Captain America: Winter Soldier, and Nick Fury "died".  He doesn't have the same level of immediate news and access that he previously enjoyed.  The Agents of SHIELD tv series shows that at this time, SHIELD is considered an underground (if not terrorist) organisation.  This, combined with Wakanda's mostly secretive nature, means that he wouldn't know about what was happening over there.

While it's certainly conceivable that he was aware of the New York/spaceship attack, the news reports shown were discussing (if I remember correctly) a missing Tony Stark afterwards.  Nick may have assumed, without any other contradictory information, that since the spaceship is gone Iron Man has handled it.

Thanos is not a threat that Nick knows about (as far as we've seen so far).

> With no Tony(missing), and no Steve (on the run), when he sees what happens to Maria Hill, he sends a message to (presumably) Captain Marvel.

Comment: When did Dr Strange do that in the movie? I just remember him about to use the time stone but was prevented by Ebony Maw.

Comment: You refer to the scene early on where Strange waves his hands about a bit and then half winks at Tony, who half smirks back, just before Maw & the big one beam down. I believe all Strange did there was disperse the dust.

Comment: Um yeah, where did you get this Strange using time stone bit? He tried but Maw interrupted his ability to start controlling the Time Stone

Answer (score 2):

This is entirely speculation: From an out-of-universe perspective, considering that Kevin Feige stated that Captain Marvel is the strongest character they will have introduced, it would make sense to not have her show up in Infinity War.

I'm not really familiar with the character at all. Presumably she would have been more of a match for Thanos and, along with the Avengers and Guardians, the screenwriters might not have been able to prevent her from turning the tide.

When you look at how the movie ends, it seems clear to me that they wouldn't have wanted some new mysterious character to swoop in and do that.

Answer (score 2):

Because she is always Nick's backup plan as elaborated in canon comics, from [screenrant](https://screenrant.com/infinity-war-nick-fury-captain-marvel-wait-reason/)

> The official [Captain Marvel Prelude](https://www.marvel.com/comics/issue/71576/marvels_captain_marvel_prelude_2018_1) comic offers the first clues. There's one brief conversation, set at the same time as the end of Captain America: Civil War, in which Nick Fury and Maria Hill discuss heroes. Hill is evidently disappointed in the Avengers, and doubting the wisdom of this entire initiative. "I've heard something else said about heroes," she observes caustically. "Never to meet them. They'll only ever let you down." It's an observation Fury objects to, and he gives a swift response; "Not all of them."
>
> Eternally observant, Hill realizes that this seems to imply there's still another hero in play. "You got one we haven't called yet," she asks, clearly curious. **"Might be helpful to have a backup plan in case the worst should ever come."** In case readers were doubting this conversation was about Captain Marvel, Fury ends it with a simple response; "Nah. If we do our job right, we'll never be in a position of having to call **her**."

Clearly indicated it's Captain Marvel.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a comics fan and have only seen the movies.

But, my assumption would be - as an audience we do not know the answer to that question yet, and we won't likely know until Captain Marvel comes out next year.

They have released that the Captain Marvel movie is set during the 90s though, so presumably something happens during this movie that either puts her out of action (which may be why as of Iron Man, Nick starts putting that Avengers together in the first place) or for some other reason she is indisposed.

So realistically it's the same question as to why Thor wasn't in Civil War. The answer to that was in Thor: Ragnarok.

The movies are a series, we just have to wait for the next one.

Answer (score 0):

If you've seen the movie a couple times then it becomes pretty clear that Nick Fury simply didn't know enough about Thanos until it was too late.

If you stretch the question a bit further, though, "Why didn't Fury call during the NYC attack or about Ultron?", then you have a much more interesting question.

One theory I haven't seen yet:

Imagine you've got a bank heist going on. Who would you call?

The police can probably handle it. They've got the tools and experience to sufficiently eliminate the threat.

If Iron Man is around, isn't too busy, and is willing to participate, then he could probably handle it better than the police. His technology and experience is superior. It'd be overkill to call him about every bank robbery, but you could be forgiven for doing so if you felt like the robbers were unusually dangerous. As Tony told Peter in Homecoming: "*Forget the flying Vulture guy. There are people who handle this sort of thing.*"

Then there's Hulk... you **don't** call Hulk for a bank robbery because using him comes at great cost. Hulk is a destroyer, much like a bomb. You don't use him unless the situation warrants it. You would try to handle the situation with less raw, destructive power.

Perhaps the Captain Marvel character we're about to be introduced to comes with some costs. Perhaps she attracts *the wrong crowd*™, or her powers, once unleashed, are difficult to control. Maybe she just doesn't care that much about human life or collateral damage. Who knows... she might not have been much more useful in the NYC attack then that nuclear missile, which is why Fury chose not to call her.

But, if half of the universe is dying or already dead... well then the costs associated with using her may actually be warranted.

Answer (score -2):

I'd imagine it will take her time to get to earth say a couple of months, like how it took Thor two months to get to Sakar. She wouldn't have been back in time to beat the nuke, levithian or sokovia dropping if he called her any time before. At the end of Infinity War he knows Stark is off the planet and multiple ships are over Wakanda, instead of just one ship over New York like the previous two times. When people dissolve before his eyes he knows he has no options even if she doesn't arrive for a couple of months because the escalation of problems is too much for him and Hill and whoever may or may not be alive to fix themselves.